# Docusign for Salesforce Essential Managed Package issue

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

After I installed "Docusign for Salesforce Essential" in my org. I did navigate to "Docusign Setup" Tab. When I tried to click "Login with docusign", I got error that you need to setup your domain. After I did setup my domain. Now Everytime I go to "Docusign Setup" tab, it redirects me to login page and when i login it says "Page Setup doesn't exist". Has Anyone got this type of error?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it sometimes happens when you installed DocuSign before creating your custom domain. Uninstall the app and reinstall and follow the installation path again the error shouldn't appear.